# Getting the database object from the LongListSelector Item

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector that is populated with List which contains objects from SQLite database:

```
     protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DB_PATH);
      var query = conn.Table<Prasanja>().Where(x => x.id == 3);
      var result = await query.ToListAsync();
      foreach (var item in result)
      {
           var query1 = conn.Table<Odgovori>()
           .Where(y => y.Prasanja_id == item.id);

            txtPrasanje.Text = item.Tekst;
            var resultOdgovori = await query1.ToListAsync();

             foreach (var itemOdgovor in resultOdgovori)
            {
                Lista.Add(itemOdgovor.Odgovor.ToString());
                lstOdgovori.ItemsSource = Lista;
            }
       }
```

What I want is when one of the LongListSelector items is tapped that I get the specific object tapped, and have the ability to use that object properties.Here is my code:

```
       private void lstOdgovori_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
        if (selector == null)
            return;

       Odgovori odg = selector.SelectedItem as Odgovori;
         if (odg == null)
           return;

      if(odg.Tocno==null)
       MessageBox.Show("Try again");
        else MessageBox.Show("True!!!");
    }
```

The problem here is that my object **odg** from the class **Odgovori** returns null after executing this code. How can I fix this?

Comment: first check is thr value present in selected item by applying Break point on line..**Odgovori odg = selector.SelectedItem as Odgovori;** if thr is value present then the problem is with type mismatch..

Comment: Yes, the value is present. My problem is that the object **odg** from the class **Odgovori** returns null after executing that line. How can I cast the SelectedItem as Odgovori object properly?
Odgovori is my SQLite table class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your OnNavigatedTo method you have the following line

```
Lista.Add(itemOdgovor.Odgovor.ToString());
```

This means that you are adding a string and NOT an instance of a `Odgovori` object. From your example, the `resultOdgovori` variable is a List so each item in it is already of type Odgovori. You should modify your code to be as follows.

```
lstOdgovori.ItemsSource = await query1.ToListAsync();
```

This will populate the LongListSelector with the collection of Odgovori objects. When you do this you will need to modify your ItemTemplate of the LongListSelector so that it will display values properly

```
<phone:LongListSelector>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Odgovor}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```